# OnClosing event not called for minimized to tray app

Tags: qt, qml

When QT application is minimized to tray, and you shutdown PC, onClosing event in QML code isn't triggered.
Is there any other way to catch the moment when the app is closing in this scenario?

Comment: main (int argc, char *argv[]) { int exitCode = qtApp.exec(); /* here your saving actions */ return exitCode; }

Comment: @Deep main() also not being called when app is minimized to tray.

Comment: But here you can check minimized state of window(s) of your app. Stop! You want save minimized state between runs? Incorrect!